# Build a MAMP environment on Mac... Best solution?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, phpmyadmin

I recently bought a new mac... In the past I used [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) and [Bitnami](http://bitnami.org/stack/mampstack) for the setup of my dev environment, but I would like to find a more efficient way, if exists, to manage my apache & php installation...

So...

What is the best way to set up a PHP development environment on a Mac? On StackOverflow I found something on http://www.macports.org/ are they reliable and/or updated to latest versions of apache and php?

Comment: Hello. I had exactly the same question some days ago. The solution I found was to create some VirtualHosts in the httpd.conf, which work well for me.

Comment: How much more efficient than MAMP can you get? Or what's your definition of "efficient"?

Comment: @deceze well.. I want a clean installation (not messing around my mac), up-to-date stuff, easy manteinance and easy shutdown/restart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am one of the BitNami developers. I wanted to mention we have released a version of MAMP stack that you can download and run from Mac OS X app store with one click. It is completely free: https://itunes.apple.com/app/mamp-stack/id571310406

Comment: The BitNami MAMP Stack in the App Store doesn't seem to work in Yosemite -- any plans to update it? I'm on a corporate network where we are allowed to use App Store apps but not non-App Store apps.

Comment: Unfortunately we have tried multiple times (a *lot* of times) to update our offering in the app store but Apple acceptance process is completely broken. Unfortunately we will be pulling all of our apps from iTunes. You can always download the installers from our page. They are completely self-contained, so easy to install / remove without messing with the rest of your system (you can even install multiple environments side by side, only thing will be choosing different ports if you want to run them simultaneously)

Answer (score 5):

I finally found my perfect setup thanks to this blog post: http://echodittolabs.org/blog/2011/09/os-x-107-lion-development-native-apache-php-homebrew-mysql-or-mariadb, which basically uses Lion's built-in Apache and PHP with a [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installation of MySQL and a nice VirtualHosts setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com) new MAMP/WAMP Stack. I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Apache/MySQL/PHP on linux servers several times, and it's usually a piece of cake because of good package managers.

However, I had a terrible experience with MacPorts. Why don't you look at [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) if it has everything you need.

Comment: But with XAMPP beware of missing security described on their web site:
1. The MySQL administrator (root) has no password.
2. The MySQL daemon is accessible via network.
3. ProFTPD uses the password "xampp" for user "nobody".
4. PhpMyAdmin is accessible via network.
5. MySQL and Apache running under the same user (nobody).

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going for an Ubuntu Virtual Machine, for several reasons...

- Easy to mantain (all packages available)
- Easy to shutdown
- MacOS stays clean
- I can easily switch env or similar...

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users i recommend "Softaculous AMPPS" since it's easy to update it. For Mac users I recommend "Bitnami MAMPStack". However to test PHP mail function on my Mac, i use "MAMP Pro".